# Gatsby Styles Breaking -- Netlify Deployment

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

This is my first post here, so forgive me if I am not upfront with anything.

I have a Gatsby site that is being deployed via netlify.

Been running into a very random bug that I have searched the dark reaches of the internet but cannot find the fix for.

Intermediately, the site styles on my website break completely. Upon inspecting, I see my global.css file isn’t being applied. Upon a refresh, this issue goes away.

Site is accessible by this link: https://ellicottrealty.netlify.app/ 2

Upon looking online, I see that I should define the css export in my Gatsby-browser.js file.

I have done so explicitly by writing the following:

const React = require(“react”)

// gatsby-browser.js

import “./src/global.css”

However this is still happening in my app.

Screenshot attached for reference. Any help would be very helpful!

Thanks Guys!

[Example of Broken Styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGVQ2.png)

Loom video for better visual context: https://www.loom.com/share/05e9234636304eeea44d2ae8337c542c

Comment: Try adding the error logs, not the images or the video. It's really difficult to debug with the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at a symptom and not the cause. I see that your site is loading infinitely on the `/properties` route. It's very hard to debug the problem without the total context, but I believe the infinite loop is in this code.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log("ran");
  if (searchOptions) {
    console.log(searchOptions);
    if (searchOptions.label) {
      console.log(searchOptions.label);
      Cookies.set("locationLabel", JSON.stringify(searchOptions.label));
    }

    console.log("ran");
    services.repliers.getListings({ ...searchOptions, page }).then(setListings);
  }
}, [searchOptions, page]);
```

Like I said before, it's hard to figure out what your exact problem is without enough context. Maybe you should add `listings` to the dependency array as well?